# How to get Condensate Pump to talk to Sonoff 4CH Pro R2

Tags: switch, home-automation, relay, condensate

I currently have a WiFi water alarm triggering a Sonoff 4CH Pro R2 to kill my whole house humidifier. So I have some experience with triggering the relays and getting the two devices talking to each other via IFTTT.

Here is my question as I want to take things a step further. I want to be able to kill my AC and Whole House Humidifier when the condensate pump fails. I have a Sonoff 4CH Pro R2 and a Little Giant 554425 VCMA-20ULS with a safety switch. How to I go about sending a signal to the Sonoff when the condensate pump safety switch is triggered? Is there another WiFi device I need to purchase or is there a hardwire way?  Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[Sonoff 4CH Pro R2](https://www.itead.cc/sonoff-4ch-pro.html)
[Little Giant 554425 VCMA-20ULS](http://littlegiant.com/products/hvac/condensate-removal-pumps/vcm-series/vcma-20-series/)

Comment: Do you really want to rely on the WiFi router being up in order to have the condensate pump interlock with the AC to work?

Comment: i would run a local copy of node-red to replace the internet-based ifttt. i'm not usre i understand your setup, but you can use a smart outlet to power a dc wall wart that engages a relay to switch about anything.